# Limit of conjugate is conjugate of limit

Tags: complex-analysis

> Show using an $\epsilon-\delta$ proof that
>   $$\lim_{z \to z_0}{g(z)} = L \iff \lim_{z \to z_0} \bar{g}(z) = \bar{L}$$

Can someone provide me with some hint? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$|\bar{z}| = |z|$ and $\overline{z-w} = \bar{z} - \bar{w}.$ Just write down the definitions of each limit and use those properties.